# Archiving SharePoint 2010 List with Attachments

Tags: attachments, storage, archive

I have a SharePoint 2010 site collection that runs a complex change management process using multiple lists.  The site collection has a **10 GB** storage limit.

The change management process requires that each list item have an attachment, which means the site might run out of storage fairly quickly with regular use.

So, I need to offload the completed items to an archive location in order to keep the SP site content from outgrowing the storage space. The archived content needs to include the attachments, either within the archive file or in the same location and linked somehow to the archive file.

Options for archive locations include using another SP site collection or using an Access DB stored on a file share.

Looking for options/suggestions, pros and cons for various options.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing to take advantage of the Information Policy management with SharePoint designer workflow to copy the list items from one site collection to other.

basically you define Information management Policy with SharePoint Designer Workflow.

here is the blog which help you step by step method, his Workflow move list items within site collection but you have to amend it accordingly.

http://referpages.com/wp/2012/04/101/

Main Points:

1. First, create a new list (destination) having the same columns
   and settings as the existing (source) list.
2. Second, create a workflow to copy items to the destination list
   and delete the item from the source list.
3. After creating the tasks listed in the prerequisites, you can setup
   the Information management policy settings.
4. Define the event to initiate the retention policy and the action
   to be performed when the event is triggered.

Comment: Cant we use Transfer to another location with List ?

Comment: what you mean, i cant understand?